# React - change button color after clicking

Tags: reactjs

I have the following button:

```
{this.steps.map((step, index) => (
    <Button variant="raised" color={(step.answer === 'done' ? 'primary' : 'default')}
                            onClick={this.markAs('done', step)}>
                                Done
                            </Button>
)}
```

my `markAs()` function looks like this:

```
markAs(value, step) {
        step.answer = value;
    }
```

Although `step.answer` changes to `done`, the color of the button stays the same.

```
class App extends Component {
   steps = [...some steps];
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: is step a state?

Comment: @Rodius steps is an array of objects I declared

Comment: As you're not using React state, the component won't be re-rendered when a custom attribute you have created is changed. If use `setState`, it will force a re-rendering of the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use react component `state`. Initialize the defult value for correspondent button. And change state after it is done.

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
  }
  steps.forEach( (item,i) => {
    this.state[i] = 'not done'
  })
}

renderStep(step,stepId) {
  return (
    <Button
      variant="raised"
      color={this.state[stepId] === 'done' ? 'primary' : 'default')}
      onClick={this.setState({[stepId]:'done'}
    >
      Done
    </Button>
  )
}
```

in render you need to call like this (where `stepId` is position in step array)

```js
<div>
  {renderStep(step,stepId)}
</div>
```

Comment: `answer` is a property of a `step` object inside my `steps` array, I can't use your solution

Comment: Ok I add processing of array for you. Check new edition. But I need to notice that explanation how to use state and so on which need to solve your question but write full application as you need is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

A React re-render can only be triggered if a component’s state has changed. The state can change from a `props` change, or from a direct `setState` change. The component gets the updated state and React decides if it should re-render the component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     step: { answer: '' },
   };
   this.markAs = this.markAs.bind(this);
  }

  markAs() {
   this.setState({ step: { answer: 'done' } });
  }

  render(){
   return (
     <Button
       variant="raised"
       color={(this.state.step.answer === 'done' ? 'primary' : 'default')}
       onClick={this.markAs}
      > Done
      </Button>
   );
  }
}
```